# jQuery height() function not working on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently in the process of putting together a jQuery touch carousel. I seem to have run into a slight problem when setting the height (or width) of an element, however.

Below is the relevant code from the function:

```
carousel = function( container, options )
{
    this.settings = $.extend({

        // General settings:
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        slides: 'div',
        snapTo: true,
        mouseSupport: true,
        trackMovement: true,
        slideWidth: 600,
        slideHeight: 400,

        // CSS classes:
        wrapperCls: 'carousel_wrapper',
        innerCls: 'carousel_scroll_inner'

    }, options);

    this.container = container;
    this.scroller = null;
    this.slides = this.container.children(this.settings.slides);
    this.numSlides = this.slides.length;
    this.scrollWidth = this.settings.width * this.numSlides;

    this.container.addClass(this.settings.wrapperCls);
    this.scroller = $('<div />').addClass(this.settings.innerCls);
    this.container.wrapInner(this.scroller);

    this.scroller.width(1500)

    this.scroller.css('width', this.scrollWidth);
    this.container.css({ width: this.settings.width, height: this.settings.height });
};
```

This is in turn called by doing something like:

```
$(function() {
    var carousel1 = new carousel($('#myElement'));
});
```

`#myElement` definitely exists, and no error is thrown. `this.scroller` also contains the correct jQuery object which has been wrapped to the contents of `this.container`. The problem is that I am unable to set the CSS width or height of `this.scroller`, using either the `width()`, `height()` or `css()` functions.

What am I missing? I have put together a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KfUdT/) to demonstrate the problem. If you check the element inspector, you can see that the dimensions are never updated for the `div.carousel_scroll_inner` element.

Comment: I know that I can get it to work like that, but that's not my question. I don't want to chain the `width()` function. There's no real reason my code doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, here:

```
this.container.wrapInner(this.scroller);
```

jQuery will use a copy. So `this.scroller` is not the same element wrapped around whatever is below `this.container`. Try:

```
this.container.addClass(this.settings.wrapperCls);
this.scroller = $('<div />').addClass(this.settings.innerCls);
this.scroller.append(this.container.contents());
this.container.append(this.scroller);
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that `wrapInner()` actually created a copy of the wrapping element. +1.

Comment: @BenM Me too ;) Actually I'm still trying to find prove for that. It could also be that this is a specific case, because the wrapping element hasn't been attached to the dom yet. ;)

Comment: Just another quirk of jQuery (or the DOM) perhaps. Thanks again, that had been bugging me all morning!

Comment: @BenM I guess this is it, have a look at the jquery source, and look for `var wrap = jQuery( html, this[0].ownerDocument ).eq(0).clone(true);`

Comment: That should definitely be documented somewhere in the API!